# Dev Late to Git and Github: Give Her .git Dir?

Tags: git, github

A friend and user of one of my open source apps has hired a dev to move the project along. The dev does not know git at all, and I don't want to insist on her learning too much (instead of working on code; not my choice).

She downloaded the tarball of the repo and has started working. I'd now like to get her back under version control and working in a branch.

The plan that I've thought of that involves her the least is to prepare a local git repo that talks to the right branch, and send her the .git directory. That way she can pop in the .git directory in her working copy. Then all she has to do is `git add .; git commit -a -m "whatever" ; git push` or something similar.

Then all I have to do is help her set up her SSH keys for Github.

Am I missing anything? I know, I know, I know, many of you will say, "it's a great opportunity for her to learn git" etc. etc., but again, that's not my call, and **I don't want to lose the new dev work.**

Comment: I don't know what you should do, but you might tell her that learning git (or any version control system since it seems like she's not using one at all) is a good investment for the future.

Comment: How does what you describe keep her from learning git? All it does is turn "git clone <address>" into several unnecessary steps...

Comment: If someone isn't using git properly, you are going to lose a lot of time... You need to know a tool to use it.

Comment: To supplement what mathepic says: sure, you could create a single sequence of commands that would get everything from the working directory pushed to a central repo, but you're asking for trouble. You'll have to deal with ensuring her commits are always fast-forwards relative to origin. Unwanted content is going to get checked in sometime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're going to do something like this, where a dev has no idea how to use git and may not be making commits properly, **don't give her push access to the central repo**. Set up a personal central repo for her, get your simple commands worked out (`add; commit; push` and `pull`), and review everything from there before you merge it into your true central repo. You don't want any problems stemming from lack of git awareness to be published.

Also, if you do something like this, you'll have to be sure that her commits are always based on the tag for the tarball she grabbed. If you don't, you might end up putting a commit at the tip of master which reverts a lot of content back to the state from the tarball. Basically, you'll have to *manually* keep track of a lot of the things that should be dealt with by the VCS.

Comment: thank you for this pragmatic approach to the problem. I was going to delete the question; now I'm glad I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd recommend the peepcode videocast about git(http://peepcode.com/products/git), is a really good one, and learn real usual stuffs.

You have to worry about "git add ." (maybe git add -i would be better), mainly if the project have configuration files, and files that don't have to be commited.

I think that use git without use local branch is not a good way (because pull conflicts and so on), so I would teach the dev how to use a local branch (git branch, git checkout, git merge).

Hum.. and i think that you have to teach him the git pull command.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good, workable plan. One thing you haven't accounted for is if she's added new untracked files. You'll want something like:

```
git add .; git add . -u; git commit -m "whatever" ; git push
```

If other people are working on the project, perhaps the best plan would be if she had her own branch - both local and remote - so as to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to have her check the GitHub repo out into a new directory, and the recursively copy everything from her old directory on top of the new Git repo.  Since this doesn't modify the old non-Git working directory, it's ok to screw up the new Git repo and try again.